# SpriteKit SKPhysicsBody with Inner Edges

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-physics, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have created an `SKSpriteNode` called let's say **Map** that has an edge path that I have defined (some simple polygon shape).

What I am trying to figure out is how to add several *other* edge paths that would act as interior edges of the **Map**. As if the "map" as a whole did in fact have *holes*. Some sort of inner boundary shapes that could act with **Map** as a whole: one edge path (as shown below)

[image]
©

I understand that there is a method that allows for creating an `SKPhysicsBody` with bodies (some NSArray), like such

```
Map.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:bodiesArray];
```

Does this method in fact generate what I have shown in the image? Assuming that the `bodiesArray` contains 3 `SKSpriteNode`'s each with a defined path from using such method:

```
+ (SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath:(CGPathRef)path
```

, with creating the path like such

```
        SKSpriteNode *innerNode1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"map"];

        CGMutablePathRef innerNode1Path = CGPathCreateMutable();

        CGPathMoveToPoint(mapPath, NULL, 1110, 1110);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(mapPath, NULL, <some x1>, <some y1>);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(mapPath, NULL, <some x2>, <some y2>);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(mapPath, NULL, <some x3>, <some y3>);
        . 
        .
        .
        CGPathCloseSubpath(mapPath);

        innerNode1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:innerNode1Path];
        [bodiesArray addObject:innerNode1];

        // Repeat for other 2 nodes
```

I understand that an alternative would be to create 3 separate nodes with the location and shape of the intended "holes", but I am tying to avoid creating more nodes than I need. If anyone can confirm what I am trying to do is correct, or perhaps suggest an alternative that I am unaware of.

**NOTE**: IF what I am doing is correct but I am missing something, I would appreciate it if someone can show me the correct way to do what I am trying to do (even a simple example of a square with an inner smaller square would be great). Thanks!

**EDIT 1**:
Below is the code snippet that I am using as an attempt to create the "inner boundaries". This issue here, is that while both the outer and inner rect's are drawn and shown, when I add the inner rect to the Map `bodyWithBodies`, it takes full control of the collision detection, removing all contact control from the outer rect shell. When I remove the `bodyWithBodies` it goes back to normal with showing both rects, the outer has collision detection (does not allow me to pass through), while the inner one has nothing... so close

```
// 1 Create large outer shell Map
CGRect mapWithRect = CGRectMake(map.frame.origin.x + offsetX, map.frame.origin.y + offsetY, map.frame.size.width * shrinkage, map.frame.size.height * shrinkage);

self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0);
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

// 2 Create smaller inner boundary 
CGRect innerRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 300);
SKPhysicsBody *body = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:innerRect];
body.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;
NSArray *bodyArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:body];

// 3 Add bodies to main Map body
myWorld.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:bodyArray]; 
myWorld.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;


if ( [[levelDict objectForKey:@"DebugBorder"] boolValue]  == YES) { 
    // This will draw the boundaries for visual reference during testing       
    [self debugPath:mapWithRect];
    [self debugPath:innerRect];
}
```

**EDIT 2**
This approach works..by just adding a new node with the same properties as the outer rect:

```
SKPhysicsBody *innerRectBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:innerRect];
innerRectBody.collisionBitMask = playerCategory;
innerRectBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;
SKNode *innerBoundary = [SKNode node];
innerBoundary.physicsBody = innerRectBody;
[myWorld addChild: innerBoundary];
```

...but I would very much like a cleaner solution that does not require additional nodes..thoughts?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithTexture:alphaThreshold:size:

Comment: In my edit I have shown what I have done but (as explained) just not quite. I know I can create a separate `node` that can mimic the performance of the larger outer shell, but again, I'm just trying to avoid having more CPU stress. I figured something like this should be possible given Apples range of usability with SpriteKit.. :(

Comment: recheck your collision and contact masks

Comment: without changing any of the contact bit masks, when I use the rect path only for the outside, it works fine, but when i had the inner body through `bodyWithBodies` only that inner geometry detects collision

Answer (score 1):

you are doing nothing wrong here i come with an example where i created two edge rect bodies with two physics bodies

//adding bodies after some time using gcd

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self addBodyA];
    });

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self addBodyB];
    });
-(void)addBodyB
{
    SKSpriteNode *node=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
    node.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node.frame.size];
    node.position=CGPointMake(550, 420);
    node.physicsBody.restitution=1;
    [self addChild:node];

}
-(void)addBodyA
{
    SKSpriteNode *node=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
    node.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node.frame.size];
    node.position=CGPointMake(400, 420);
    node.physicsBody.restitution=1;
    [self addChild:node];

}
-(void)addEdgesBodies
{
    SKAction *r=[SKAction rotateByAngle:1.0/60 duration:1.0/60];

    SKSpriteNode *rect=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(300,300)];
    rect.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:rect.frame];
    rect.position=CGPointMake(500, 400);
    [self addChild:rect];


    //
    SKSpriteNode *rect1=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(100,100)];
    rect1.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:rect1.frame];
    rect1.position=CGPointMake(550, 450);
    [self addChild:rect1];


    [rect1 runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:r]];

}
 [self addEdgesBodies];
```

remember edge bodies comes with low cpu overhead so don't worry about performance untill your polygon don't have so many edges.

Comment: thank you for the help - I appreciate it. so this approach will actually achieve inner interactive* boundary conditions (as the picture i showed)? Or will this just create this circumstance visually

Comment: I have created a large rectangle with a smaller inner rectangle but now it seems that the inner rect is the only area to take the boundary conditions, while I can pass through the outer rect now. This was done using bodyWithBodies (my code is above in an edit to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Your code for making a path then using it in a physics body looks like it would work.  As well as your physics body from bodies.  Unfortunately I do not know SKPhysicsBody's can really support holes because you can not flip the normals of the body.  The way I read apples documentation is that it is meant to do things like take two circle shapes and make them into one body, rather then creating a complex shape like that.  The problem being that having a hole inside of your bigger shape would mean ignoring collision in that area.

**Here are some alternative options**

One option is you could build your stages from multiple shapes.  For example if you break your map into two pieces (with a line going through each shape) and make physics bodies for those.  Then have them overlap and make them into one body then it might work out.  I made a diagram showing this (pardon its terrible quality you should still be able to understand what it is doing (hopefully)).
[image]

Another option would be to make it with a texture, this can hurt preformance a bit but if you can manage it then it probably would work nicely.

```
Map.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: Map.texture, size: Map.size)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am in absolute need of independent bodies within the main boundary. I did consider this though as this would be a work around if I can not figure out a clean way of achieving what i need :)